# emacs color-theme by buffer

Tags: emacs, buffer, org-mode, emacs23

I'm in love with emacs. I don't believe there is anything one **can't** do with enough effort!

I have just fine **working** scripts/extensions installed that could be relevant to get my point:

- `org-mode` (with a CAPTURE-TEMPLATE named "Journal")
- `color-theme` ([emacswiki](http://emacswiki.org/?ColorTheme))
- `theme-changer` ([github](https://github.com/hadronzoo/theme-changer))
- `color-theme-buffer-local` ([github](https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local))

`emacs-version`: "GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.10) of 2012-03-25 on roseapple, modified by Debian"

Whats already working fine
When I'm starting a journal-entry trough my defined shortcut, what happens is the following:

- emacs opens a new ***buffer***("CAPTURE-journal.org") in a new ***window***
- I edit it
- with another keystroke the entry gets refiled to my defined journal.org file
- the ***buffer*** and the ***window*** are then closed automatically
- I continue working on the file I worked before

What I want it to do additionally:

- the "CAPTURE-journal.org"-***buffer*** in the new ***window*** should have a unique color-theme, lets say `color-theme-retro-orange`

My [`.emacs`](http://txtup.net/8rlYr) with the code snippet I believe should be relevant.

I have no idea how to tackle this task. Where does one begin editing? Are even all tools needed for this listed above?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I noticed you have `color-theme-is-global` turned on.  Would that override the buffer-local settings?

Comment: How did you define a shortcut to open a new buffer ("CAPTURE-journal.org") in a new window?

Comment: @cm2: Good point. I honestly have no idea, whether it overrides or  not. But I will defintely give it a try!

Comment: @Deokhwan Kim: The new buffer is opened by the build in [CAPTURE-function](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html) of org-mode. By the way "a new **window**" means a new **emacs-window**.

Answer (score 1):

Seen from scratch: you need a list with color-themes

(setq my-themes (list "color-theme-retro-orange" "second-theme" "third...))

than you need a pointer, storing position used last.
See Emacs Lisp Intro chapter of kill-ring-save

When finished, bind that function at a suitable place, where-from your buffer is opened, resp. load it with the stuff mentioned by OP.

Or create a minor-mode, which will all new buffers provide with this.

Comment: I hope I didn't get you wrong. The [Capture-function](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html) works just fine. The only thing I am missing is the mentioned theme-change after the new buffer is opened.
It should come down to evaluating one line of elisp-code after the buffer is created and active. [ referring to [color-theme-buffer-local](https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local) this line should be `(color-theme-buffer-local 'color-theme-retro-orange (current-buffer))` ].
Now I can't figure out where to put this line without editing the code of the original `org-mode`-files.

Comment: looks like color-themes is the list, where its selected from

Comment: my-color-theme-buffer-local would replace the prompting by proceeding described above but keep the rest of body for applying it.